# Html files on Google app engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I am developing a web app using Google App Engine, in this case I am usin Python 2.7 I have the app.yaml configured like this

```
application: googleappengine01
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
- url: /html
  static_dir: html
- url: /html/(.*\.html)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/html/\1
  upload: static/html/(.*\.html)

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

When I launch the app I can use for example the user api to validate users, but once I click a link to another html on my app I get this  {{ url_linktext }} {{user.nickname}}.

How can I solve this so I can validate all my html files

Comment: You are serving your html files as static files.  But, it looks like you are using Jinja or Django, or similar, for user auth.  If that is the case, you don't serve the html as static files, but as templates within the Django/Jinja/etc system.  Please clarify.  Instead of static files, you want to ue something like `return render(my_template.html)`

Comment: Danger: you say you're using Python 2.7, but you aren't -- `runtime: python` means you're using **2.5** (and should migrate to `runtime: python27` ASAP as 2.5 support in GAE is deprecated and will be decommissioned!).